# Unity3D: AR Foundation - CameraConfigFilter?

Tags: android-camera, augmented-reality, frame-rate, arcore, android-augmented-reality

We noticed, that google pixel devices have a locket 60 fps camera configuration, which blocks focusing. This also impacts the AR Foundation App experience.

You can see this information also at the supported device list on google: 
https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

On the other hand - there is a possability to generate a camera config file, but as it seems only when working straight with the ARCore SKD in Unity3d:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/camera-configs#camera-filter

My question: We would have to fix those devices to run their camera on 30 fps to make the app work propper. I have set the Application.targetFrameRate to 30 (i dont think this effects the camera - so it wont work), but i would like to know if there is a possibility to generate a camera config file for AR Foundation like on the Unity3d ARCore SKD.

Thank you very much.